# Put files in newly created external storage folder on first launch

Tags: android, android-external-storage

My Android app creates a folder on the users device's external storage on launch:

```
File images = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + "rapical" + File.separator);
images.mkdirs();
```

I have around 16 image icons (.png) that I would like to place in this folder the first time the user opens the app.

What is the best practice to do this? Should I place them in the drawable folder initially and then copy them over to the newly created images folder? Not sure what approach to take!

Comment: "I have around 16 image icons (.png) that I would like to place in this folder the first time the user opens the app" -- why would the user want to see these icons in their gallery app? What is the value, to the user, of having these on external storage, rather than just using resources?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I'm fairly new to the Android business. What approach do you think I should do instead then?

Comment: The normal way of using icons is to have them simply be drawable [resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html). There is nothing stopping you from doing what you describe in your question. However, it's an unusual approach, and it has some issues (e.g., the icons will get indexed by the `MediaStore` and will show up in other apps, like the a gallery app). If you describe your technical objectives, we can perhaps provide you with more concrete recommendations.

Comment: @CommonsWare Users can add foods to the SQLite database with the option of adding an image too. The image is re-sized, compressed and stored in the folder I created in my question, alongside the location of the newly created image location being stored in a column (as a String, atm looks like "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/rapical/filename.png") in the database for this food. Users then later on select a food by the image referred in the database. 

On initial launch of the app, there are some default foods added and I would like images to be added too. What folder should I use for the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues here:

1. What to do with images that the user adds to your app?
2. What to do with your starter images, for your default foods?

---

Using [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) for the user-added images has some implications:

- Your app can survive that image no longer existing, since the user, or other apps, can delete that file at any point
- Your user does not mind that the image will get picked up by other apps, such as photo galleries

Unless you *specifically* want these images to be user-manipulable outside of your app, I suggest that you use [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) for the "re-sized, compressed and stored" user-supplied images. The original image might be on external storage (I assume that you are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and/or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to get the image), but your modified copy would be private to your app.

---

I sincerely hope that you are using an [image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), for loading these images, since they will handle things like background threads and `ListView`/`RecyclerView` image recycling and stuff for you.

In that case, what you store in the SQLite database for your default foods needs to be something that the image-loading library can interpret, to bring in the image that you want.

In that case, I would suggest using `assets/` to ship the images and `file:///android_asset/...` values in the database. `file:///android_asset/` points to what amounts to `assets/` in your project, so if you have `assets/chicken_pad_thai.jpg` in the project, Picasso (and any decent image-loading library) would be able to interpret `file:///android_asset/chicken_pad_thai.jpg`) and load the image.

This saves you from making duplicate copies of the images, saving the user disk space and time on first launch. It also means that if you replace the images in your app (e.g., you get a better photo representing chicken pad thai), the user will start seeing the updated image, without you having to do some extra work to realize that you shipped a new image and have to copy that image out to a file somewhere.

---

Now, suppose that you really *do* want the user-supplied images to be on external storage. In that case:

- Probably rather than the directory that you chose, I would go with `getExternalFilesDir()` (a method on `Context`), as on API Level 19+, you do not need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` as a permission
- If you want the user to be able to manipulate the images of the default foods, then copy those out to that location on first run

Comment: So with regards to users uploading their own images - I would use getFilesDir() to locate the internal storage for the app? This shows as '/data/data/com.packagename/files' - would this be correct?

And for the images that are shipped with the app, if I put them in the 'assets' folder, I would have to refer to them as `file:///android_asset/file_name.png`, correct?

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your time and effort - this will help me out loads. It's for my university final year project so it means alot to me. I've never used Picasso but i'll give it a whirl now. If it all works fine then I'll accept the answer. Again, thanks.

Comment: So far so good - Picasso is loading images from the asset folder nicely. Now just to test with user-uploaded images from the internal storage then we are set sail :)

Comment: I'm having trouble locating the internal storage folder on my phone - I'm using ES file explorer to locate it and I'm having no luck - any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @blueprintChris: You can't see it, except on a rooted device. That's the point. It is private to your app.

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically find out if the files I'm putting in there are actually being put in there?

Comment: @blueprintChris: Write some instrumentation tests (e.g., `androidTest/`). Or, see if they show up when you display them in your app.

Comment: Been working on this most of the day - it's working brilliantly, thanks! Got both asset images and internal storage images working!! :D